# Websphere EAR module dependency management

Tags: jboss7.x, classloader, dependency-management, ear, websphere-8

I have an EAR with the following structure

myWar1.war
   WEB-INF/lib/myJar.jar

myWar2.war

I want myWar2.war to be able to load myJar.jar.
In JBoss 7/EAP 6.x you can add a dependency like this in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<sub-deployment name="myWar2.war">
    <dependencies>
         <module name="deployment.myEar.ear.myWar1.war" />
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
```

I don't know of a WAS equivalent. I have tried adding a class path entry in myWar2.war's manifest file but WAS seems to ignore it.
If I have a manifest entry such as

Class-Path: myWar1.war/WEB-INF myWar1.war/WEB-INF/lib myWar1.war/WEB-INF/lib/myJar.jar

myWar1.war/WEB-INF and myWar1.war/WEB-INF/lib are added to the module class path but myWar1.war/WEB-INF/lib/myJar.jar is not

I know I can turn the jar into a utility jar at the EAR root level but would prefer not to. It's an established application (the second war is new) I don't want to mess around with it too much. If I can solve the dependency with a class path entry that would be ideal.

Comment: I actually would have expected the manifest classpaths to be relative to the root of the current WAR file, so I was surprised the first two worked for you. (I was wondering if you might need to try like ../myWar1.war.) Almost seems like a bug for the first two to work, but not the 3rd. What version of WebSphere, and what fix level?

Comment: @dbreaux `Class-Path` is always relative to the containing archive, so I believe the syntax is correct, but this is just not supported.

Comment: Using WAS 8.5 FP2
Trying ../ doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  JARs in WEB-INF/lib are considered to be local classpaths to myWar1.war, and you can't reference JARs from another WAR.  Your only option is to move the JAR to the EAR (either the `lib/` directory, or to another directory and add `Class-Path` to the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` of both WARs).